# Histogram Intersection Kernel

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification

I want to calculate and use a histogram intersection kernel for a text classsification problem with SVM. I'm using bag of n-grams with `CountVectorizer()`. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
# Libraries    
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# Dataset
d = pd.read_csv("d.csv").to_numpy()
x_tr, x_tst, y_tr, y_tst = train_test_split(d[:, 0], d[:, 1], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# Bag of n-grams
c = CountVectorizer()
b_n_g = c.fit_transform(x_tr)

# Histogram Intersection Kernel
# ...
```

Comment: Afaik this is very specific and unusual. I wouldn't expect any standard library to have this implemented. Why do you want do this?

Comment: @Erwan I am testing several precomputed kernels for SVM and choose the best with cross-validation

Comment: So are you looking for a SVM library which accepts custom kernels? Or you want to implement SVM yourself?

Comment: @Erwan I want to create a custom kernel and using it within scikit-learn

Comment: I don't know about this myself, but apparently there's [some documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html).

Comment: @Erwan Ok thanks, I will take a look and implement the kernel from scratch.